# Cannot get Raspberry Pi 4 and Arduino to communicate successfully using nRF24L01+ wireless modules

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am having some problems getting my Raspberry Pi 4 and Arduino uno to communicate successfully using nRF24L01+ wireless modules.

I have tried several different youtube tutorials and this the 3rd time i've come back to this project only to be met with failure.

For the arduino I am using the [TMRH20 RF24 library](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24)

The tutorial I have most recently followed is this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_68f-yp63ds).

The code used in the tutorial for the arduino is a basic transmit only code:

```
#include<RF24.h>

//ce,csn pins
RF24 radio(9,10);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.setChannel(0x76);
  radio.openWritingPipe(0xF0F0F0F0E1LL);
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
  radio.powerUp();

}

void loop() {
  const char text[] = "Hello World";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  Serial.println("sent.. ");
  delay(1000);
}
```

The code used in the python script on the raspberry pi 4 is receive only:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [[0xE8,0xE8,0xF0,0xF0,0xE1], [0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0xE1]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0,17)

radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)

radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1])
radio.printDetails()
radio.startListening()

while True:
 while not radio.available(0):
  time.sleep(1/100)

 receivedMessage = []
 radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
 print("Received: {}".format(receivedMessage))
 print("Translating our received message into unicode characters...")
 string = ""

 for n in receivedMessage:
  if (n >= 32 and n <= 126):
   string += chr(n)
 print("Our received message decodes to: {}".format(string))
```

Both programs compile.

The details outputted by the RPi terminal (because of radio.printDetails()) are:

```
/home/pi/nrf24/lib_nrf24.py:377: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  self.GPIO.setup(self.ce_pin, self.GPIO.OUT)
STATUS   = 0x03 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=1 TX_FULL=1
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0xfdf9f9f9f9 0xfefefefef8
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0xf0 0xf1 0xf1 0xf1
TX_ADDR          = 0xfdf9f9f9f9
RX_PW_P0-6       = 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
EN_AA            = 0x0f
EN_RXADDR        = 0x00
RF_CH            = 0x1d
RF_SETUP         = 0x00
CONFIG           = 0x03
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0x03 0x01
Data Rate        = 1MBPS
Model            = nRF24L01
CRC Length       = Disabled
PA Power         = PA_MIN
```

I'm fairly confident that theres communcation happening between the RPi and the radio as when I disconnect the radio and re-run the python script the hex values shown above all go to 0.

I have noticed that on the youtube tutorial the RX_P_NO is different, as is the TX_FULL value.
Additionally, the RX and TX addresses are not the same is the ones entered in the python script.

I have had the radios communicating using two Arduino Uno's before. I think my inexperience with python is hindering me here.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: In the tutorial, the python script outputs a string every second. My script outputs blank strings several hundred times a second. Perhaps there is an error with the python code as it is supposed to wait in the while loop until data is available. If not it may be an issue with the radio.available() function.

Comment: Did you try `radio.stopListening();` on the transmitter? Are there any LEDs on either module? If so, are they flashing/lit?

Comment: I've tried ```radio.stopListening();``` in the setup function on the sender. No change. There is a power LED on each radio board that is lit.

Comment: You could add a debugging `print('Waiting for data')` above `time.sleep(1/100)` to see what's happening maybe. And change to `time.sleep(1)`

Comment: The message `"Channel already in use"` also maybe implies that the board needs to be powered down between unsuccessful attempts.

Comment: You could try disabling the CRC on the sender with `setCRCLength(0)` since it appears disabled on the receiver... or enable it to CRC8 on both.

Comment: I tried disabling the CRC on the arduino as suggested. I now get some data received on the Raspberry Pi! However it is not the data I am expecting.. 

```Received: [54, 54, 59, 63, 63, 63, 24]
Translating our received message into unicode characters...
Our received message decodes to: 66;???
```

Comment: Ok, well that's maybe some progress. As the data looks so poor, maybe you could do CRC8 (8-bit) on both ends to see if that makes it more reliable. Also I would get the payload size with `radio.getDynamicPayloadSize()` as each message arrives, and print the payload size along with the raw message. That will tell us if the data is consistently wrong or randomly wrong, i.e. if it keeps changing despite always sending a constant length `"Hello world"` string!

Comment: I do not think it was progress at all in fact. I removed the code and got the same result. I've changed the radio and no there is no data being received, perhaps a faulty unit. I've put it to one side. 

Yes i tried to radio.setCRCLength(16) on both sides and the arduino gave me an incorrect parameter error. I'll try 8 now.

Answer (score 1):

The warning you are getting is likely related to your problems.

The printDetails() output indicates a communication issue between the RPi and the radio. For example, RF_CH shows as 0x1d when it should be 0x76. This indicates a wiring or configuration issue.

My best suggestion would be to use the TMRh20 RF24 Python wrapper for the RPi. This way you are using an actively supported library, the code base is exactly the same from Arduino to RPi, and it includes known working examples.
See http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/Python.html

Note: You need to build the C++ library first, as it is a Python wrapper for the C++ library

Comment: I will abandon the old method and try this library instead. I will let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: @JFirmware Are you able to do anyhting about this to make things work,I am facing the same problem when I follow the above tutorial on youtube